# gdb in Netbeans-7.4 for C++ debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans, gdb

I'm trying to debug my project using the "step-into" function, but each of the debug options (other than Debug Project, Attach Debugger, and Debug Core File) is grayed out.  I've checked on both my Linux and Windows machines, and they both have the same problem.

I'm running Netbeans 7.4 with gdb 7.6, seemingly properly loaded under tools->options->C++.  Is there possibly a compatibility issue with newer versions of gdb?  If so, how can I revert to an older version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you can try:

1. Remove *all* breakpoints of your project and try again with a *new* one
2. (If possible) test version:

   1. a earlier version of GDB
   2. and newer version of NetBeans (current stable: NB 7.4 SP2 -- testing: NB 8.0 RC1)
3. Are there any error messages? Please also keep an eye on NetBeans's logfile - on IDE start and debugging
4. Check your paths, e.g, to compiled binaries / libs

Maybe this Bug can help you: [**Bug 233683 - Gdb doesn't work with NetBeans 7.3.1**](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233683)
It's posted for 7.3, but maybe it's still in 7.4.

Comment: A small GDB update has been released today for Netbeans 8 (RC1), possible this solves that issue. Btw. please refer to the linked bug report, a solution is mentioned in the last 2 comments.